# Renaming table name

Tags: php

I am trying to rename a table's name from a specific database. I have tried with both of the query given below, but it shows the same error message. I can't understand my mistakes.

The query

1st one :

```
  <?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
$dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
$olddept_id = $_SESSION['olddept_id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$order = "UPDATE department SET department='$_POST[department]', dept_id='$_POST[dept_id]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("RENAME TABLE $olddept_id TO $dept_id;") or die (mysql_error());

}
```

and

2nd one :

```
  <?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
$dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
$olddept_id = $_SESSION['olddept_id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$order = "UPDATE department SET department='$_POST[department]', dept_id='$_POST[dept_id]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $olddept_id RENAME $dept_id;") or die (mysql_error());

}
```

The error message is :
    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO CSEE' at line 1"

The table names which i want to edit, are also stored in a table, named "department". This is done successfully, but the table doesn't renaming.

-thank you

Comment: Can you show some example data? And you should protect your queries against SQL injection

Comment: You shouldn't ever be renaming your tables from the user end of things.  Organize your data differently.

Comment: The main table is "department". When i store a name of department like CSE, EEE or ME in that table, then i want to make same three types of different table named as CSE, EEE and ME. @Pekka, I am begginer of it, i don't have any other idea dear. :(@Brad

Answer (score 0):

Show the exact SQL that's generated by those queries. I'm guessing you're using a reserved word for the original table name, which means you'd have to escape it with backticks:

RENAME `reservedword` TO CSEE